# Google signin from android app - What to do after signed in success?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I"ve read [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435319/what-is-the-recommended-way-of-authentication-after-google-signin), but im still not clear how i would authenticate a user after a successful google signIn.  I have an idea and im looking for approval from you.  After a successful google signIn i will have access to the GoogleSignInAccount object. In this object i can do something like store the token and users email as the credentials into a remote db so i can recognize the users profile on my servers end. This could look something like this from android client side:

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        //now that i have an account lets store the token
        String loginToken=acct.getIdToken();
       storeTokenInRemoteDb(acct.getEmail(),loginToken);
        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
```

Is this the best practice to authenticate after good signIn success ?

Comment: Check out http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html ... get an ID token, POST it over HTTPS to your server, verify it on your server, use the subject as the key in your user DB, and issue a session token or cookie to your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me I send the token to my server and then I validate it in the server side with sending request to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN
```

That will return something like this if the token is still valid

```
{
  "audience":"8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "user_id":"123456789",
  "scope":"profile email",
  "expires_in":436
}
```

And then I will also store the token locally in case the user logged out from my app and try to re-login with same google id and the token is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to access data such as name,emails etc

```
            Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                final String name = acct.getDisplayName();
                final String email = acct.getEmail();

                signOut();

                if (name.contains(" ")) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {

                        if (name.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                            firstName = name.substring(0, i);
                            lastName = name.substring((i + 1),
                                    name.length());

                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with my question. I am talking about how to authenticate user on my server after successful google signIn process

Comment: I am trying say same.just use email retrived and send it to your server.Check its available in DB.IF yes then send it to login else register user.

Comment: i see what your saying. your not worrying about a token. your just using the email address to identify the users profile, right ? Do you think its wise to store the users account token in the servers db ? The token could become invalid right ?

Comment: Its depend upon your application logic

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add something.  The email address should not be used as the primary key for your local or webserver storage after authenticating the google account.  You should use the account ID as user can have multiple email accounts but will alwyas have the same account ID.

So you could do it like this:

```
String accountName=Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
String accountID = GoogleAuthUtil.getAccountId(accountName);
```

now that we have the accountID we can go ahead and use it as as the primary key in any database locally or on a webserver.  How else can you handle multiple email accounts ?Or what if user changed the primary email address.

some more info is [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2014/10/tips-for-integrating-with-google.html)

The other thing i wanted to mention is that a hacker could attack your server by just keep guessing the email address of the user, so i would not base it on email address.  I would use a token. After i get a token from the google sign in process i would let the android client upload the token to my server but then i would let the server speak to google servers to again verify the email address with this token and verify the token itself.